# Xcode add Github account not possible

Tags: xcode, github, xcode10

Unable to select add Github (grayed out) in Xcode 10. Source control has been enabled. Any idea what causes this?

[image]

Comment: It's interesting that there's a spinner still spinning in the lower left of the dialog. This suggests there's some other problem behind the scenes. At the very least I'd try restarting the computer.

Comment: For example, are you connected to the Internet? You can't use this interface otherwise, because your Github username/password can't be confirmed. The spinner suggests that at this moment we're having trouble confirming your Apple ID, perhaps because your Internet connection is momentarily missing...?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I'm connected to the Internet, have no trouble accessing my Apple ID, have tried restarting the computer and removing Xcode preferences. The issue persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with the GM version (10A254a). Updating to the final 10.0 build (10A255) via the App Store fixed it for me.

Comment: 10A255 suffers from the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same issue and could solve it with

- Make screenshots of the custom preference settings
- Delete `/Applications/Xcode`
- Delete all files containing `com.apple.dt` `in ~/Library/Caches`
- Delete all files containing `com.apple.dt` `in ~/Library/Preferences`
- Open App Store.app, download and re-install Xcode.
- Create the Apple ID developer account

After those steps all account types were enabled and I could create the GitHub account.

Finally restore your custom preference settings from the screenshots.

Comment: Thanks - I just needed to close Xcode, then restore those two files with Time Machine from a few days back, and it worked without deleting Xcode and needing to reinst.

Comment: I am having the same issue and following this it made no progress ... I cannot add ANY source control account...

Answer (score 0):

no need to do anything , just download xcode 11 or later from Apple app store and then open XCode 10. it will start showing git add options . now u can uninstall xcode 11 which u downloaded . it will work perfectlly

Answer (score -2):

Here is exactly solution

Simply Restart Your Mac