# Xcode stuck on wrong git branch

Tags: xcode, git, locking, branch

When trying to change branches I got an error saying my credentials were bad. Since then, **Xcode shows the wrong branch.** When I'm in command line it allows me to change branches, pull, commit etc...

- When I try to change branches in Xcode, it says the repository is locked.

  - There's no lock file in .git and I can change from terminal (xcode doesn't change)
- I've wiped derived data, restarted etc...
- I completely deleted the project and recloned from GitHub Enterprise.

  - For a second it seemed to work...
  - but I tried to change branches and my old branches showed up and I got frozen again.
  - had to clone to the same directory however

**Where is this state being cached so I can delete it and start fresh?**

**EDIT:**

I've completely deleted Xcode, redownloaded the version I'm using (10.3), deleted these caches:

> sudo rm -R ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt
>
> sudo rm -R ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt

as per this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52541405/4522329

After I was setup, I reconfigured my Apple ID and GitHub Enterprise Account and recloned a second time.

Again things looked fine, until I tried to change branches...

**Then my previous local branches popped up again showing me back on an entirely different branch and any attempt switch throws a repo locked error.**

When I run 'git status' from command line, tons of duplicate files were pulled in from some cache and I'm shown on the branch I expect to be. I can do whatever I want from command line (still no lock file in .git), but it's not reflected in Xcode!!!

Also the launcher screen on Xcode is showing older, formerly deleted projects. There's some Xcode cache that's trying to recover from somewhere...

Comment: Seems like you need to clean the **local** settings of Xcode.

Comment: @0andriy please see edit above. If you know of a cache file I'm missing please specify.

Answer (score 0):

So this was weird. Still not sure the underlying reason.

I was able to resolve by wiping everything out again, cloning to a different location opening up in Xcode and cycling branches from within the IDE and then cycling through a few from command line and confirming the IDE was updating.

After that I moved the project to it's previous directory address. When I opened Xcode the recents list had two entries for the project in that location. I cleared both, then opened by directly clicking on my xcworkspace.

So far so good.

Comment: Sorry, have at it.